# How to remove https from https://www?

Tags: html, jackson

I have website on WordPress and its https redirect. I want to disable hyperlink and remove https from https://www.example.com in the comments field.

here is the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j91H.png

Simply I wanted to show as text www.example.com  without hyperlink and https.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `wp-content/themes/functions.php` file. This will disable automatic linking to URL's in your comments section.

```
remove_filter( 'comment_text', 'make_clickable', 9 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but sir its sill as https://www.abbaspc.net after use your code.
please can you provide more help thanks

Comment: Are you writing the comments in HTML, or is there a text editor for the comments(similar to SO)? If there is an editor in the website, it may automatically format any detected links.

Comment: its WordPress default comments system

Comment: @MuhammadAbbas I updated my answer with a solution that should work for your Wordpress site.

Comment: Thanks you so much. its work very well. I have add in theme editor Theme Functions (functions.php)